# ORACLE: Raise_application_error muestra más mensajes de lo debido

Tags: oracle

Tengo un `trigger` en oracle que realiza una validación y llama al `raise_application_error`.

```
if cuenta_goradid > 0 then

    raise_application_error(-20002, "RUC ya existe"); 

end if;
```

Pero cuando la app muestra el mensaje de error sale mi mensaje más otros;

> ORA-20002: RUC ya existe
>  ORA-6512: Eror en xxxxx, linea 50
>   ORA-040088: Error en disparador etc etc etc

Es posible que solo se muestre mi mensaje?

Answer (score 0):

NO, no es posible que muestre solo tu error para facilitar esto lo que puedes hacer es que siempre retorne el mismo tipo de variables que estas usando, por ejemplo si estas usando cursores siempre retorna cursores.

```
  create or replace procedure registrar(codigo IN int, v_return OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
    IS 

    en_cero EXCEPTION;


    BEGIN

    if codigo = 0 then
    raise en_cero;
    end if;

    open v_return for select 'hola',codigo from dual;

    EXCEPTION 
    WHEN en_cero THEN
    open v_return for select 'Error','es un cero' from dual;
    ROLLBACK;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    open v_return for select 'Error','Se ha encontrado un error al terminal la operación.' from dual;
    ROLLBACK;
    END;
```